# Group and count in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have many tweets object like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2f4a381cb29b482553e2c9"),
    "user_id" : 21898942,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2009-03-09T19:48:50Z"),
    "id" : 1301923516,
    "place" : "",
    "retweet_count" : 0,
    "tweet" : "Save the Date! March 28th Vietnamese Cooking Class! Call to Reserve 312.255.0088",
    "favorite_count" : 0
    "type": A
}
```

I'm using this code to qroup the tweets by date and by type:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "date": {
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                        "date": "$created_at"
                    }
                }, 
                "type": "$type"
            }, 
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }
]
results = mongo.db.tweets.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Here is the result I get:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "date": "2009-03-17",
        "type": A
    },
    "count": 4
,
{
    "_id": {
        "date": "2009-03-17",
        "type": B
    },
    "count": 6
}
```

But now I want to have the result in this format:

```
{date: "2009-03-17", A: 4, B: 6, C: 9}
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this through `aggregate` directly?

Note: I'm using MongoDB and PyMongo

Comment: Group by date, push type-count pairs, then use https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/ and replace root after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation query in 3.6 version.

Added the second group to create array of type and count value pairs followed by `$mergeObjects` to merge date key value with `$arrayToObject`, which produces create a type value key and count value pairs, to generate the expected response.

`$replaceRoot` to promote the document to the top level.

```
pipeline = [
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "date": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
            "date": "$created_at"
          }
        },
        "type": "$type"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.date",
      "typeandcount": {
        "$push": {
          "k": "$_id.type",
          "v": "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "date": "$_id"
          },
          {
            "$arrayToObject": "$typeandcount"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Mongo 3.4 version:

Replace the last stage with below

```
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [
            {
              "k": "date",
              "v": "$_id"
            }
          ],
          "$typeandcount"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```